# How to add page specific JavaScript files to the Laravel Assets Pipeline?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, asset-pipeline

I using Laravel Assets Pipeline(https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline) plugin for the my project.

I was able to successfully configure with the common JS files (jquery.js, global.js) included in the page. I have some page specific JavaScript files that needs to be included.

```
home.js
about-us.js
```

I tried with following but I think it's not the correct way to achieve this.

```
{{ HTML::script('assets/home.js'); }}
```

Comment: Where are the assets located? Inside "public/assets" folder?

Comment: all the assets are located at "app/assets"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [asset-pipeline documentation](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline#usage) it should be used like that :

```
    <?= stylesheet_link_tag() ?>
    <?= javascript_include_tag() ?>
```

There is a manifestFile argument which can maybe load only some specific files.

Are you sure it is compatible with HTML facade ? If it is, there is maybe a route to configure :/

And as far as I understand the documentation, you shouldn't call your script like that, one of the aim of your asset pipeline is to delegate it, isn't it ?

Comment: what if i need to load only specific js file for specific page?

Comment: Have you try the manifestFile argument ?
Here in the doc : [link](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline#usage)

Comment: I understood the real use of it. I added all the file to the manifest-file instead of including those separetly.